# Search the android market for an app, but only return the link to the app

Tags: android, google-play

I'm making a map application.

I'd like the user to see X in my app, then be able to go to the market, search for an app related to X, and add a link to that app to X, so that other users can find that app when they look at X.

For example, say someone finds a particular brand of bank on the map, and they know there's an app for that bank. I want them to be able to go to the market, find the bank app (Edit: Which I don't know even exists before the user gets my app), and then add the link to that app to the POI on the map, so that others can know about the app.

The part I'm having trouble with is, what does the Market app return? Can I get it to return a link or partial link like that? It seems to me the hardest part is that when a user selects an app, it installs it. I don't imagine it's even set up to possibly return a link instead, but I can't find much info on what it returns at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Android market API project](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/)

> This library allow you to ask directly google's official android market servers for information, search for apps

```
MarketSession session = new MarketSession();
session.login(email, password);
session.getContext.setAndroidId(myAndroidId);
String query = "HSBC";
AppsRequest appsRequest = AppsRequest.newBuilder()
                                .setQuery(query)
                                .setStartIndex(0).setEntriesCount(10)
                                .setWithExtendedInfo(true)
                                .build();

session.append(appsRequest, new Callback<AppsResponse>() {
         @Override
         public void onResult(ResponseContext context, AppsResponse response) {
                  // Your code here
                  // response.getApp(0).getCreator() ...
         }
});
session.flush();
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it out. I'll leave selecting this as the answer for a while, in case there are other suggestions, but it looks good so far.

Comment: No problem, I'm also interested in other options if any. Hope this works out for you.

Comment: Hello Reno, I pasted that code and includ one lib file (androidmarketapi-0.6.jar).

It's showing me error on 

AppsRequest appsRequest = AppsRequest.newBuilder().setQuery(query) .setStartIndex(0).setEntriesCount(10).setWithExtendedInfo(true)    .build();

Error Is : The type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I had try add and remove lib file many times.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the app, you can create an intent as explained here:
[Linking to Your Apps on Android Market](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent)

For example:
If the user selects McDonalds on the map, they can push a button to search for apps that match the name.  In this case you would do the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://search?q=McDonalds"));
startActivity(intent);
```

That should open the market up to roughly [these results](http://market.android.com/search?q=mcdonalds) in the native market.  From there, the user can select the appropriate app.

Comment: No, I don't know the name of the app. The point is to let the user decide.

Comment: Edited to include example.  The user would be brought to the market which is automatically searching for the given term.  The user can then select from the list of matches.